# Passing a command line argument as target in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

To simplify my question, if I have a Makefile as below

```
    %: %.c
           gcc -o $@ $<

    make foo
```

`Make foo` will build the executable `foo` from `foo.c`. No issues. If I were to change the Makefile as below, so that I can pass the target from Makefile command-line

```
    # To make things little complex
    TARG=$(EXE)
    $(TARG): %.c
            gcc -o $@ $<

    make EXE=foo
```

The above command `make EXE=foo` says:

> `"make: *** No rule to make target %.c, needed by`foo'. Stop.`

Why is `$(TARG)` **not** getting expanded in the `target` rule in Makefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just leave the code from your first example and add the following line:

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL := $(EXE)
```

Or (which is effectively the same) add `$(EXE) :` rule with no recipe before any other rules. By default Make picks the first target defined in the Makefile, if nothing is specified on the command line.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [Static Pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern)

```
TARG=$(EXE)

$(TARG):%: %.c
  gcc -o $@ $<

make EXE=foo
```